# PHP AJAX fileupload (large files)

Tags: php, file-upload

I wrote a PHP and AJAX(jquery) script for uploading files. It is perfectly working fine. I want to upload a file of size 500MB to 1000MB. I can update the parameters file max_upload and post upload parameters in php.ini to perform this task. But I am allowing multiple file uploads (with a restriction of 500MB to 1GB to each file and 10 files at an instance). I am not sure if it is feasible to upload files of 1GB using

```
$move = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_path);
```

I also refereed to the some stackoverflow questions. Some of them refered about breaking the entire file to chunks and upload each chunk to the server. After uploading all the chunks can be combined. Some other questions refer the above command 'move_uploaded_file' is okay. Some others refer to use FTP for this purpose(but is it good to use ftp for a user file upload ??). Can anyone say what is the best possible way to perform this task ??
Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the time you get to using `move_uploaded_file()`, the file has already been uploaded

Comment: thanks @phil, so is chunking a better way to upload files ??